# RGB2BGR option disappeared from cvtColor

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to compile my code with opencv 3.0.0 (that worked with previous opencv versions)
    cvtColor(img, img, CV_RGB2BGR);
and get compilation error
   ‘CV_RGB2BGR’ was not declared in this scope
The option also does not exist in the documentation

How can I get the same functionality (RGB2BGR) with the new version?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use constant cv::COLOR_RGB2BGR instead of CV_RGB2BGR.

It works for other convertions too, just change *CV_*   to   *cv::COLOR_* .

Just checked it it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have a namespace issue?
The enum is defined [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/3.0-ocl-tp2/modules/imgproc/include/opencv2/imgproc/types_c.h#L102), and in any case, it is exactly the same as `CV_BGR2RGB` - it just mixes the channels. You could also use `mixChannels()` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful, OpenCV 3 is something new, it is very probable that it has changed some macros and also functions and especially functionality. More it is not a stable versions, meaning it is still in dev. I have seen that there are some other names for the macros, like `COLOR_RGB2BGR`. The `CV_RGB2BGR` seems to be in [types_c.h](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/3.0-ocl-tp2/modules/imgproc/include/opencv2/imgproc/types_c.h)